# Use spatial query to load WFS data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, query, spatial-query

I tried to load a WFS into my QGIS project but the number and complexity of the polygon features are to high to handle for QGIS so that it throws an error. So I tried to add a spatial query to the request via the SQL Query Composer so that only the features in my geographic area are loaded. In the SQL Query Composer I found the dropdown menu Spatial predicates. There are a few postgis functions. Unfortunately it throws an error because the SQL query seems to be wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM AX_Wald WHERE ST_Intersects(AX_Wald.geom, ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,
-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))'))
```

The error is: Column AX_Wald.geom references a non existing field.
How can I reference the geometries from AX_Wald in my query?

Comment: If I add a WFS layer to QGIS (3.16) and open DB Manager, then expand Virtual Layers and Project Layers, I can select my WFS layer and see that the Column is "geometry". What does yours say when you look there?